# How to compile and run a C file in CodeBlocks which is outside a project?

Tags: c, codeblocks, projects

I have opened a project in CodeBlocks, which builds and runs successfully. Now if I open another C file in the IDE, the build and run command will act on the existing open project  and not on the new C file. If there were multiple projects, we can switch between them using " activate project" . But what if there is one active project and another C file outside the project. How to complile and run the C file then ?

Comment: you can with the help of a little trick

Comment: Your question might be "how to configure CodeBlock to make it compile a single C file outside of my current project", but that is a very different question.

Comment: I have an extra project "quick_test" (with a single source file) which I can open and just paste the code I want to test. Then switch back to the main project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Under the `Projects` tab on the left, right- click on your project and click `Close project`. Do this for all projects that are open.
2. Now, if your C file is open, just press `F9` to compile and run your program.

It is easy to compile and run a single C file in Code::Blocks:

1. To create the file, click on `File` -> `New` -> `Empty file`
2. After typing the code, save it with `.c` extension.
3. Press `F9` to compile and run the program.

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is *not* a compiler, but an IDE.

> How to compile and run a C file in CodeBlocks which is outside a project?

It runs compilation  commands, probably using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) (but consider also [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/)). It is the compiler which compiles your code (not CodeBlock).

So you don't compile with CodeBlocks.

<sup>(BTW, remove `gcc` on your system, and CodeBlocks become useless to build any program -both inside a project or single file- from C code)</sup>

To compile `foo.c` into some program `fooprog` you want to run something like

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -g foo.c -o fooprog
```

and you may want other arguments to `gcc` (e.g. some `-I` or `-D` for preprocessing, some `-L` or `-l` for linking libraries). Their order is important. Read chapter on [invoking GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html). The `-Wall -Wextra` asks for all warnings and more of them. The `-g` asks for debug information. The `-o fooprog` requires to output the executable `fooprog`... Details could be operating system specific.

You can run that `gcc` command in  a terminal. Perhaps CodeBlock could be configured to run it somehow (that is a very different question).

You could also learn more about [build automation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Build_automation). Consider [GNU make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/) or [ninja](https://ninja-build.org/), etc... Your [`Makefile`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Makefile) might build *several* executables (with a plain `make` command, and you could configure your IDE or editor to run it).

Notice that many [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) projects (on [github](http://github.com/), [sourceforge](https://sourceforge.net/), etc etc...) are not requiring any particular IDE (but are built using some build automation software). That could ring bells in your head. Good [source code editors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_code_editor) (such as `emacs` or `vim`) are able to run build commands (as nicely, and more generally, than IDEs). Perhaps you should consider using them.

Comment: it is a clear question about **codeblock** not **gcc** and its flags.

Comment: But you don't compile with CodeBlock because it is not a compiler; try for example to remove `gcc` and CodeBlock becomes useless

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not part of a project, I doubt you could compile it with any IDE. You probably need to either compile it manually or create a project for it.

IDEs are created to manage entire projects, not a single file.

Comment: Of course for a single file they have been created as well. Otherwise you could not use/create a single file, whereas you can

Comment: `If the file is not part of a project, I doubt you could compile` Well, CB does that.

Answer (score 0):

With a little trick you can.

Follow me for a test version:

1. create a new project
2. open that project and then run it. It works of course
3. open your single file, at this point, **codeblock** is involved the active project, and if you switch to your single file and press: `Ctrl + F9` it still builds your project and **NOT your single file**
4. **close all projects** in menu: `file`
5. **close all files** in menu `file`
6. reopen your project and your single file

Now on your project hit:

- `Ctrl + F9` for **build**
- and then `Ctrl + F10` for **run** it will run  (= or `F9` for both)

Also try this on your single file, then your single file will run as well.

---

have been tested on **Code::Blocks** 16.04; 32-bit; Ubuntu

Comment: Not working on windows 10 , if there is an active project and another open file, hitting F9 while opening the single file still builds and runs the project. The standalone file does not compile and run  unless I close all projects.

Comment: @asdf. You should close all files and projects after creating them and **reopen** them again.  I did this many times

Comment: @asdf see my answer.